# Cannot run mongod.service and therefore cannot connect to mongo

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu, systemctl

I accidentally killed my mongo local server, so every time I want to connect I have to run this command:

```sh
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
```

How can I run it automatically?
I'm missing for some reason the `mongod.service` file, so I cannot run `systemctl start mongod`.

If anyone can please provide a solution (or the missing file) it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this, I think the service will be modified and restored.

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod
```

Then run it again.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: Not working, returns `Failed to enable unit: Unit file mongod.service does not exist.
`

Comment: What OS do you use? I think you should try the following command. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. Then run the start command above again.

Comment: Still, not working. It seems like this service never existed, and I cannot understand how my mongo worked till now